# Allow pinch-to-zoom gesture when map is maximally zoomed out

Tags: zooming, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, pinchzoom

1. On a mobile device go to http://output.jsbin.com/bobaki/5
2. Pinch-to-zoom on a button and click it
3. Try to zoom out to see the whole map

It will be impossible because map will hijack all gestures (even if it's maximally zoomed out). Reloading page won't help because zoom settings are preserved between reloads.

I'm using the default settings:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'
});
```

and I'd like to change them so that when map is maximally zoomed out, mapbox stops hijacking and `preventDefault`ing zoom out gestures.

For reference, that's how it looks on my phone (I can't get URL bar to show up, I can't scroll down or zoom out):
[image: trapped in a map]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this mapbox github issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4259):

> While using mapbox gl-js on a mobile device or any device that uses
>   (touch) to move the map, an error is thrown due to the event listener
>   being treated as passive.

So, did you try to set `style.touchAction = 'none'` on the mapbox element ?

Comment: I don't see how this is related I did test setting `touch-action:none` on the container though: http://output.jsbin.com/bemuram/2 and the problem persists.